# Is there a limit for how many subscriptions one can have on google reader or the news pieces they get every day?

Tags: rss, limit, atom-feed, google-reader

Is there a upper bound to how many subscriptions one user can have in their google reader?
how about the number of news they poll every day? Google has limits on everything, how about this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of subscriptions per account is 15,000. However, if you have more than 2,000 subscriptions, then certain operations (getting unread counts, the "all items" view) may not provide accurate responses.

Comment: how about Google search subscriptions, is there a limit on those?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google search subscriptions"?

Answer (score 0):

Google support forums indicate 2,000 though I'm able to add more... may be Mihai is right.
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=250e2743c9e41796&hl=en